# I don't understand the meaning of しばらく in this sentence

Tags: translation, verbs, adverbs

I was reading a story and I found this sentence (in the previous part of the text the author wrote that a taxi driver had found someone and he had picked him up):

ところが、しばらく走っているうちに、車の中がなんとなく寒くなってきた。

First of all I don't understand the meaning of しばらく.

Another structure that I don't understand is なってくる. Why did the author put くる
after なる?

Comment: for しばらく：　http://jisho.org/word/%E6%9A%AB%E3%81%8F

Comment: for verb base -て + くる：http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n4-grammar-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B-te-kuru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure OP can look up things in a dictionary by him/herself.

While the usage may be slightly different to how you would normally see it used (しばらく待ってください！ or しばらくの間使えないよ！ etc), the meaning here too is that of a somewhat short time span.

"However, while/after driving for some time, the inside of the car became (gradually) colder."

Answer (score 0):

Also, regarding ～てくる, think of くる metaphorically. My grammar book defines it as "come to ~, get to ~; a change that takes place over time."

Here's another useful explanation: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/teform